# "Return statement outside of function" - JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

What is wrong in the below code?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Me.GetType(),
    "key",
    "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete these records?');",
    True)
```

Comment: What do you want it to do? Can you add a bit more context?

Comment: Need more code. Upload a working/buggy code to JSFiddle.

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with it? Your question title suggests you are receiving an error message. What is it? Is it a C# error or a JavaScript error? If the latter, why are you showing us C# and not the HTML/JS it outputs?

Comment: This question should not be closed. While it is lacking in detail, there is enough information to identify a definite problem. I **would** suggest to the OP that they put more effort into their questions in the future.

Comment: Similar: *[JavaScript error “Return statement outside of function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328084)*

Comment: What is the context here that [this C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript#System_Web_UI_ClientScriptManager_RegisterStartupScript_System_Type_System_String_System_String_) runs in? .NET code that runs under [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), generating HTML content with embedded JavaScript? Shouldn't it be tagged correspondingly, e.g. with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript error "return statement outside of function" means you've created a code fragment that is not allowed to exist outside of a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering a startup script; a startup script is intended to be run (no surprise) on startup. By itself, your code cannot be run on startup--there is nothing logical for it to do, i.e. where would it return?

However, JavaScript code outside of a function is legal in many cases. The following code would work fine.

**Example (VB.NET)**

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Me.GetType(),
    "key",
    "alert('I am a client-side script!');",
    True)
```

Your particular code either needs to be put into a function and called when desired, or attached to a client-side event.

Since the intention is a delete prompt, here is an example attached to `btnDelete`.

**Example (C#)**

```
this.btnDelete.Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete these records?');";
```